# Difference in conduction in metals and semiconductors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, semiconductor-physics, conductors

According to Fermi-Dirac statistics, in a metal, only certain number of valence electrons take part in conduction when they acquire an energy equivalent to KT for some temperature. 
Now my questions is:
How is this different from conduction in a semiconductor where the concentration of conduction electrons also depends on the temperature due to breakage of covalent bonds? Why should resistivity due to electronic vibrations play a larger role in a metal than in a semiconductor?
Note: I have just finished an undergrad course on quantum mechanics where we dealt with conduction in metals.

Comment: Its been too long for me to answer authoritatively, but I remember the valance band electrons being less important in conductors because they were vastly outnumbered by the freely moving electrons that were already in the conduction band, while in the case of semiconductors, there are few electrons in that conduction band besides those bumped out of the valance band.

Answer (score 0):

In a metal there are unoccupied states only differentially higher in energy than the occupied states so it takes very little energy to activate them and change the overall momentum of the "electron sea".

In a semiconductor the unoccupied states are more than kT in energy higher than the occupied states.